# Java program math equation

Tags: java, equation

I am building up a java program but don't have the right idea on how to resolve its math problem. 

The tasks I am doing are:

I have to cover the wall with wallpaper. The wall is "a"(input) meters width and "b"(input) meters height. I can use wallpaper with dimensions 1 × 1, 2 × 2 up to 2^n × 2^n (n is an input). I want to "dress" the wall with wallpapers so that I used the biggest wallpaper available as long as I can.

The output I need is just a number of wallpapers used.

**An example**: 
3 **inputs** are: a = 22, b = 29, n = 3 
 
This means the the wall is 22 × 29 and the max wallpaper is sized 2^3 × 2^3 ( 8 × 8). The wall should then be field like: 
http://postimg.org/image/4842z9ey1/ 
 
So the **output** would be 53 - number of needed wallpapers.

Since a and b can be long numbers (up to 10^18) the best thing would be do not use a loop for it. The n can be up to 30.

Know its more a math problem, but it depends on the java codning how it can beb done, so am asking it here.

Thanks

Comment: This really belongs in a maths forum if you're not struggling with the programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: This sounds like a do-my-assignment-question. Please post some code, explain your specific problems and we'll be happy to help you. What is your exact question anyway?

Comment: Actually, as you pointed out in one other comment. I am strugulling with the login on how to set fetch numbers of wallapers.  3 inputs are given but then I am stuck with the logic. Would like to do it myself  but soon as I have 3 inputs, I know the wall dimension, I dont know how to start the checking for wallpaers fits.

Comment: "*Know its more a math problem, but it depends on the java codning how it can beb done, so am asking it here.*". Me lady, you need to learn the Java language in order to do this. Try a book, or tutorials. Search the net ocean, you'll get what you want. Savvy?